# How to get the GUID of different HDD partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, command-line, partitioning, powershell, bcdedit

I was trying with BCDEDIT and DISKPART but that tools give me an ID that is not the GUID
Note: I am testing in Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the output of the [**mountvol**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490934.aspx) command:

> VolumeName: Specifies the volume name that is the target of the mount point. The volume name is of the form \?\Volume{GUID}\, where {GUID} is a globally unique identifier (GUID) (for example,
>   \?\Volume{2eca078d-5cbc-43d3-aff8-7e8511f60d0e}).

Comment: Thanks, I found this looking mountvol from your other comment "GWMI -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume | FL -property DriveLetter, DeviceID" http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/e7b2ddd6-f245-49ed-8fec-3b6e08e75369

Comment: Wasn't the OP talking partition, not volume? Can I adress a particular partition of, say..., 2 or 3 partition on a single volume (read: harddisk)?

Answer (score 3):

`mountvol` didn't help my in a similar case as I had two different disks containing two Windows installations (one broken), so you could not say, which is which. For that, after googling for a long time running `diskpart` was my rescue:

```
list disk
sel disk 1 #That is the "Datenträger 0", the 1TB HDD
list part
sel part 1
detail disk
detail part
```

giving me

```
Partition 1
Typ         : <HERE IS YOUR ANSWER ID>
Versteckt   : Ja #Hidden
Erforderlich: Ja #Necessary
Attribut    : 0X8000000000000001
Offset in Byte: 1048576

  Volume ###  Bst  Bezeichnung  DS     Typ         Größe    Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
* Volume 5         Wiederherst  NTFS   Partition    529 MB  Fehlerfre  Versteck
```

For better visualization two screenshots of the two used tools.
It has to be found out, wich of *1XXX7* and *6XXXb* correspond to *"Datenträger 0">EFI* and *"Datenträger 1">EFI* respectively as well es which of *1XXXf* and *5XXXf* correspond to *"Datenträger 0">recovery* and *"Datenträger 1">recovery* (recovery = "Wiederherstellung").

[image: Disk2VHD Backup/Imaging Software]

[image: Windows disk management tool]

Comment: I found another possible solution: issue `bcdedit /v`in an admin cmd (from here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e7b2ddd6-f245-49ed-8fec-3b6e08e75369/how-do-i-find-the-partition-guid )